# JAX-B is marshalling everything

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces

I have a class with an `@XmlRootElement(name="objectName",namespace="https:blahblah")` and some attributes in the class all with `@XmlElement(namespace="https:blahblah")`

But now I have some element without an `XmlElement` annotation. Why is it also marshalled?

I only want to marshal annotated attributes.

Code looks like this:

```
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        m.marshal(someInstanceOfSomeClass, doc );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB is configuration by exception, this means that it has default rules for converting Java objects to XML.  You only need to supply metadata where you need to override the default rules, this greatly reduces the amount of configuration that must be done.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

You can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so that only the annotated fields/properties are marshalled.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    private String foo;  // Will be marshalled

    private String bar;  // Will not be marshalled

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 4):

Make the attributes you don't want to marshal either `transient` or annotate them with `@XmlTransient`. As for the exact *why* I refer you to the [specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).

Comment: +1 - You call also specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE` on your class so that only the annotated fields/properties are marshalled.  This is useful when only a small part of your class is mapped to XML:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602338/jax-b-is-marshalling-everything/7602698#7602698

Comment: @Blaise: Thanks but I like your idea very much too. Subconsciously I always recognized the `NONE` option when it popped up in the content assist but I never gave much thought to it.